# How to check if struct is persisted or not?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

Is there a way to figure out if struct is persisted or not? I started digging source for Ecto's `insert_or_update` but with no luck as it hits some private method. I want to accoplish something like this:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:whatever]
  |> do_a_thing_on_unsaved_struct 
end

defp do_a_thing_on_unsaved_struct(struct) do
  case ARE_YOU_PERSISTED?(struct) do
    :yes -> struct
    :no  -> do_things(struct)
  end
end
```

Is it possible, or I'm doing something dumb?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the `.__meta__.state` of the struct. If it's a new one (not persisted), it'll be `:built`, and if it was loaded from the database (persisted), it'll be `:loaded`:

```
iex(1)> Ecto.get_meta(%Post{}, :state)
:built
iex(2)> Ecto.get_meta(Repo.get!(Post, 1), :state)
:loaded
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I also found `Ecto.get_meta(struct, :state)`. My tests are getting tripped up on something, but it's probably my factories.

Comment: Actually, it seems that somehow I get `Ecto.Changeset` fed instead of struct I'd expect: `key :__meta__ not found in: #Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: #PedalApp.Waypoint<>, valid?: true>` Even though it's coming from `Repo.get!`. What's going on here?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm actually passing changeset, not original struct there.

Comment: You can get the struct from the changeset using `.data`, so that'll be `Ecto.get_meta(changeset.data, :state)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `struct.data.id` if the struct's primary key is `id`:

```
defp do_a_thing_on_unsaved_struct(struct) do
  if struct.data.id, do: struct, else: do_things(struct)
end
```